# Unable to open a Lightning Component from Lightning Action button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have added a Lightning Action button on Contact.
[image]

I'm trying to open a Lightning Component on click of this button. But it fails with the below error.

**AddAttachmentComponent - Lightning Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction" >
<div>Priview</div></aura:component>
```

**JS Controller**

```
({
   doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
           console.log("Test");
   }
})
```

**Error on button click**

Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.
Action failed: forceChatter:lightningComponent$controller$doInit [cannot use the given object as a weak map key]
quickActionHandlerHelper.js failed to create component - forceChatter:lightningComponent

**Kindly help me out.**

Comment: Do you have any JS Controller or Helper ?

Comment: I have a JS Controller, but I have not used its method. Updated my question with JS controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a browser related issue, I was facing this error on Firefox v31 on Mac. Tried the same on Google chrome and worked properly.

After updating to Firefox-v52.0.2 the problem was resolved.

Initial Error: [cannot use the given object as a weak map key]

Comment: I've seen similar issues with JS that runs on Salesforce specifically when run from Firefox on a Mac device - no issue on a windows device.